# Can citrus to run procedure?

Tags: citrus-framework

I have one question. In Citrus frame work I can't to run sql procedure.It is look like that sql(datasource).statement("BEGIN Procedure name END"). The procedure packet is stored in the database.

Comment: sql(subsapi)
   .statement("BEGIN")
   .statement("CHARGE_RESP_PROCESSOR.PROCESS_CHARGE_RESPS();")
   .statement("END");

Comment: com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [BEGIN]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: РЎС‚СЂРѕРєР° 1, СЃС‚РѕР»Р±РµС† 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod

Answer (score 0):

This problem i decided by next query sql()
            .statement("call CHARGE_RESP_PROCESSOR.PROCESS_CHARGE_RESPS();");